# tpm_crb: probe of MSFT0101:00 failed with error -62

Tags: boot, lenovo, 22.04, tpm

The problem is that ubuntu 22.04 when i upgraded it from 21.10 i got the error below, after some time searching i found a similar [old resolved issue!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/intel/+bug/1596469)

```
[    0.000000] efi: SMBIOS=0xaf054000 ACPI=0xafffd000 ACPI 2.0=0xafffd014 ESRT=0xaeee4000 MOKvar=0xa8891000 RNG=0xaeee5a18 TPMEventLog=0xa1ea8018 
[    0.000000] TPM Final Events table not present
[    0.017405] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AFFFA000 0004B7 (v02 LENOVO Tpm2Tabl 00001000 INTL 20141107)
[    0.017413] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000AFFF8000 000034 (v03 LENOVO TP-N1G   00001850 PTEC 00000002)
[    0.017507] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0xafff8000-0xafff8033]
[    4.759925] tpm tpm0: Operation Timed out
[   11.583944] tpm tpm0: Operation Timed out
[   11.583965] tpm_crb: probe of MSFT0101:00 failed with error -62
[   11.665192] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
```

The consequences of this error are:

- I can't turn on after sleep mode
- The computer does not turn off immediately after shutdown

*Lenovo Yoga 260*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here on a Lenovo Thinkpad X260.

Temporarily fixed it by disabling TPM in BIOS

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
As I dual boot Windows, disabling the TPM causes problems when logging into Windows, so if I want this to happen I need to remove any Windows key or password or encryption before doing so !

Comment: Sure. I reported a bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1971567

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the **Intel Platform Trust Technology** in BIOS:

[image: Intel Platform Trust Technolog]

Answer (score 0):

On new Lenovo I had to switch my TPM from 'Pluton TPM' to 'Discrete TPM2.0' **AFTER** suspending bitlocker in Windows 11 (still in dualboot due to some apps not working in wine).
After that 'journalctl -k --grep=tpm' clearly shows the TPM was detected an initialized.

As far as I know, newer kernels should support the new tech , but my distro is a little bit behind.